# Why Tkinter doesn't bind a function to an event correctly?

Tags: python, events, tkinter, binding

I'm making a simple program in Python 3 by using Tkinter. We start with a black canvas in a full-screen tkinter window and I want to show a blue circle in the middle of the canvas when I press the space bar on my keyboard.

I tried this code:

```
from tkinter import *

class TheBlueCircle:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.ws = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.hs = master.winfo_screenheight()
        self.master.geometry(str(self.ws)+'x'+str(self.ws)+'+0+0')
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, bg = 'black')
        self.canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
        self.canvas.bind('<KeyPress-space>', self.drawCircle)

    def drawCircle(self):
        r = min(self.ws, self.hs)/3
        coord = (self.ws/2-r, self.hs/2-r, self.ws/2+r, self.hs/2+r)
        self.canvas.create_oval(coord, fill = 'blue')

root = Tk()
TheBlueCircle(root)
root.mainloop()
```

But it doesn't work. No matter how many times I press the space bar. It doesn't get to apply the drawCircle function.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some changes needed in your code. First you need to take an `event` as arg for your `drawCircle` method. Secondly, the current focus is not set to the `canvas` object.

To have your method correctly executed upon tabbing `space`, either first press `tab` when you launch your GUI, or force a focus change in your code:

```
class TheBlueCircle:
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        self.canvas.bind('<space>', self.drawCircle)
        self.canvas.focus_set()

    def drawCircle(self,event=None):
        ...
```

Comment: Wow, you are right. But now I need to understand where was the focus on if there is only one widget (the canvas). And how you realized that the focus was not in the canvas.

Comment: The original focus is set on the root window. Focus doesn't just change when you mouse click on something, but tabbing definite switch focus.